# Magenot 2 SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename.sales_order' doesn't exist

Tags: magento2, database

I'm getting an error when I navigate to the order grid section of the magento 2.3.4 under Sales -> Orders in the admin panel. It appears to be referencing the wrong table because table 'databasename.prefix_sales_order' does exist but below the error is calling table'databasename.sales_order'. How would I fix this?

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'databasename.sales_order' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `prefix_sales_order_grid` AS `main_table`  LEFT JOIN `sales_order` ON main_table.entity_id = sales_order.entity_id [] []
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this command? `bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Comment: Yes I tried that and the issue still is not fixed,